Configuring firebase rewrites with react + static html
I'm working on a website that requires fast load times for a specific function, for which i require to host a html + js + css file separate to the react app.
I've configured the rewrite to this:
{
  "source": "/:order_id/:item_id/:side",
  "destination": "/redirect.html"
}

However once I deployed my app it still tries to load up the react app.
the url that I entered was
https://domain.web.app/PHD6sb8NYHpW33/csi/l

what am I doing wrong?
I cannot do it through my server as the react app will be hosted on the domain, and my server would be running on another endpoint.
The point of this is similar to how netflix has a react app but implemented a vanilla page for their login for fast load times

Firebase Hosting doesn't offer placeholder rewrites (using colon prefixed names), so what you're trying to do isn't possible as written.  See the documentation on rewrites for a full review of what's possible. Be sure to expand the detailed example section.
The documentation states that the source property can be a glob or regex, so you could use that to match path segments.  Though you should be careful about writing something that matches all possible URLs.  You probably need something in your path, perhaps a static path prefix string, that the glob or regex can use to match only the paths that should be rewritten.
